# Android audio capture

Tags: android, audio, media, audio-recording

I'm following [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html#example) article to capture Audio on Android. I thought it will be easy, but there's a problem. Here's the code:

```
    File dir = activity.getDir("recordings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File file = new File(dir, "testaudio.mpeg4");

    FileUtil fileUtil = new FileUtil();
    File parent = file.getParentFile();

    if(!parent.exists()){
        Log.i(TAG, "Creating non-existent path:" + parent.getAbsolutePath());
        parent.mkdirs();
    } 

    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);

        try{
            recorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
            recorder.prepare();
            recorder.start();
        }catch(IOException e){
        //more code
        }
```

So, it does create a testaudio.mpeg4 file under /data/data/com.myapp/app_recordings/ folder. But, after transferring the file to Mac (using adb pull) it doesn't play. I am on a Mac and I've tried a few audio formats (e.g. MP3, MPEG, 3GP etc.) but nothing seems to be working. Any help/guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
File dir = new File(Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording/");
```

Comment: But, I don't want to write to external storage.  activity.getDir("recordings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) lets me write to privately to the app.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a Mac issue, nothing wrong with the code or device. I can hear the Audio on the device.